# Perl Win32::Console error

Tags: perl, perl-module

My little Perl script on Windows tried to call a dependency library `C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Term/ReadPassword/Win32.pm` which was written by somebody else.

Here is a part of `C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Term/ReadPassword/Win32.pm`:

```
package Term::ReadPassword::Win32;
use strict;

if (IsWin32()) {
  eval('use Win32'); 
  eval('use Win32::Console');
  eval('use Win32API::File');
} else {
  eval('use Term::ReadPassword');
} 

...

my $CONIN = new Win32::Console(Win32::Console::STD_INPUT_HANDLE());
my $CONOUT = new Win32::Console(Win32::Console::STD_ERROR_HANDLE());
...
```

The following error showed up when running my script:

```
Undefined subroutine &Win32::Console::STD_INPUT_HANDLE called at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Term/ReadPassword/Win32.pm line 58, <STDIN> line 2.
```

Using parens is legit, as discussed [How can I optionally use Win32::Console and its constants in a cross platform way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121421/how-can-i-optionally-use-win32console-and-its-constants-in-a-cross-platform-wa) and I've looked up http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Console.

Thanks.

Comment: In addition to cjm's answer below, make sure to `use warnings;`.

Comment: So what was the problem that was preventing Win32::Console from loading, and how did you solve it?

Comment: @cjm Thanks for the answer. It looks like the strawberry Perl I installed on my PC did not install Win32::Console correctly. Reinstalling it using ppm fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eval('use Win32::Console');
```

doesn't do any error checking.  If Win32::Console fails to load for any reason, the code will proceed anyway until it actually calls one of the subroutines that was supposed to have been loaded, but wasn't.  At that point, you'll get failures like you describe.

What happens if you add `use Win32::Console;` to your script?  (I'm guessing you'll get some kind of error saying Win32::Console couldn't be loaded.)